# Error "symbol not found" and multiplication error

Tags: java, asynchronous

Why do I keep getting the error

> symbol not found

for `hamburger`, `cheeseburger`, etc.? I also am getting an error for the `*` sign. I used a template to create this program. I don't understand why it is not compiling.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

    public class Assignment2
    {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    final (double) HAMBURGER_COST = 2.75;
    final (double) CHEESBURGER_COST = 3.25;
    final (double) FRENCHFRIES_COST = 2.50;
    final (double) BEVERAGE_COST = 1.50;

    String hamburger, cheeseburger, fries, beverages;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);//allows user input


    System.out.println("Welcome to the In-N-Out Burger menu:");
    System.out.println("______________________________________");
    System.out.println("Hamburger $2.75");
    System.out.println("Cheeseburger $3.25");
    System.out.println("French Fries $2.50");
    System.out.println("Shake & Beverage $1.50");

    System.out.print("How many hamburger(s) would you like to buy?");
    hamburgers  = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("How many cheeseburger(s) would you like to buy?");
    cheeseburgers = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("How many French fries would you like to buy?");
    fries = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("How many drinks would you like to buy?");
    beverages = scan.nextInt();

    double hamburgerCost = (double)HAMBURGER_COST * hamburger;
    double cheesebugerCost = (double)CHEESBURGER_COST * cheeseburger;
    double frenchfriesCost = (double)FRENCHFRIES_COST * fries;
    double beverageCost = (double)BEVERAGE_COST * beverages;
    double orderCost = (double)hamburgerCost +  (double)cheesebugerCost + 
    (double)frenchfriesCost + (double)beverageCost;
    int numberItems = Hamburgers + Cheesburgers + Fries + Beverages;

    NumberFormat fmt1 = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    System.out.println("Hamburger Cost : " + fmt1.format(hamburgerCost));
    System.out.println("Cheeseburger Cost : " + fmt1.format(cheesebugerCost));
    System.out.println("French Fries Cost : " + fmt1.format(frenchfriesCost));
    System.out.println("Order Cost : " + fmt1.format(beverageCost));
    System.out.println("Shake & Beverage Cost : " + fmt1.format(beverageCost));
    System.out.println("Total number of items ordered : " + numberItems);
    }
    }
```

Comment: `hamburgers` vs `hamburger`. You declare the variables with an 's' on the end, then try to use them without the 's'. Voted to close as this is just a typo.

Comment: Possibly because you define variables hamburger, cheeseburger but then assign strings hamburgers, cheeseburgers ? The variable names need to match.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I made the changes you suggested and that helped, but, I  am still getting errors for the '*' and the scan .in.